# vue 3 composition api method is undefined from emit

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have this method `updateLocation` calling `location`

```
setup(props, context) { 
  const updateLocation = (location = null) =>{
    if(location) {
      center.value = location
      context.emit('mapChange', context.location())
    }
  }
  const location = () =>  { return {
    center:center,
  }
}
```

but I get `context.location is not a function. (In 'context.location()', 'context.location' is undefined)`

I also tried without `context`

and also calling the method works from other functions; just not from `emit` apparently

Comment: How did you injected the `location` function into the context? Can you show us the plugin?

Comment: I did not "inject" anything; not sure what you mean. this is the only code related to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to rename `location` argument:

```
const updateLocation = (loc = null) =>{
if(loc) {
  center.value = loc
  context.emit('mapChange', location())
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The `context` parameter has only 3 properties `emit`, `attrs` and `slots`, you could pass `location` by props like :

```
setup(props, context) { 
  const updateLocation = (location = null) =>{
    if(location) {
      center.value = location
      context.emit('mapChange', props.location())
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I cannot access method from props ? I tried anyway; does not work

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `context` if the function is within the same scope.
Just give it a different name or it will shadow the variable `location`.

```html
<script>
export default {
  setup(props, context) { 
    const getLocation = () => {
       return { center: center }
    }

    const updateLocation = (location = null) =>{
      if(location) {
        center.value = location
        context.emit('mapChange', getLocation())
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean ? the method is in the same file; why would I need to create a new file and import it ?

Comment: Well it wasn't clear it was in the same file...
Then you don't have to use context, just run the function because it's in the same scope... I updated my answer.

Comment: Do you have any error with the code like this?